# Оптимизация SQL-выборки из большой таблице

Tags: php, mysql, sql

На сайте есть раздел "Каталог". Там выводятся 10 товаров с их статистикой за всё время. Он открывается за 5 секунд. Работодатель недоволен и хочет чтоб открывался хотя бы за 2.

Как это выглядит на сервере:
Идет выборка 10 товаров. Потом в цикле по ним собирается статистика из таблицы заказов. Проблема в том что таблица заказов очень большая. И будет только расти. А статистика нужна за всё время.

Все возможные индексы добавлены.
Я бы группировал где-нибудь статистику товаров за всё время в отдельной таблице... но в сборе статистики есть нюансы.
Например у заказа может быть партнер (столбец `partner_id`). И автор товара, например, может исключить нескольких партнеров, чтоб в этой статистике они не учитывались при подсчете.
Тогда мне приходится делать запрос `WHERE partner_id NOT IN (айдишники)`

Также в этом разделе есть сортировка товаров за неделю. Так соответственно берутся не все заказы. А только за неделю

То-есть даже если группировать в отдельную таблицу, то по дням и группируя по партнерам... И то я не уверен что это поможет

Пробовал суммировать столбцы всех 10 товаров за один запрос. Но время выполнения запроса все-равно примерно 2,7 сек.

Вот пример запроса для сбора статистики каждого товара:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS orders_paid,
    SUM(`amount`) AS `amount`,
    SUM(`products`.`price`) AS `price`,
    SUM(`price_for_author`) AS `price_for_author`
FROM
    `orders`
JOIN `users` `author` ON
    `orders`.`author_id` = `author`.`ID` //Автор товара
LEFT JOIN `users` `partner` ON
    `orders`.`partner_id` = `partner`.`ID` //Партнер товара
INNER JOIN `products` ON `orders`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` //Товар заказа
WHERE
    (
        (
            `author`.`is_statistic` = 1 AND
            (
                (`orders`.`partner_id` IS NOT NULL AND `partner`.`is_statistic` = 1) 
                OR `orders`.`partner_id` IS NULL
            )
        ) //Включаем только те заказы, автор и партнер которых отображаются в статистике (is_statistic = 1)
    ) 
    AND `products`.`site_id` = '48' 
    AND `orders`.`status` = 'paid' //Включаем только оплаченные заказы
    AND(
        `orders`.`partner_id` NOT IN(
            //Тут список id исключенных партнеров
        ) OR `orders`.`partner_id` IS NULL
    )
```

Ниже приведу результат выполнения EXPLAIN EXTENDED этого запроса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Прошу подсказать что можно придумать для ускорения

Comment: Без плана выполнения (получаемого по explain) говорить по конкретному запросу не о чем

Comment: Покажите DDL таблиц и план запроса

Comment: А так да, вы правы, если исходных данных много - возможно нужны таблицы с готовыми результатами. А вот в каком разрезе, это отдельный вопрос, надо смотреть не только какие вообще запросы бывают но и как часто какие из них бывают. Может оказаться эффективным например держать даже несколько подготовленных разрезов. А может часть все таки надо собирать на живую, для особо сложных условий, группировка по которым слабо сокращает количество записей

Comment: `products` - меняйте LEFT JOIN на INNER, ибо на верхнем уровне условий есть ``AND `products`.`site_id` = '48'``

Comment: Вот ещё неясный фрагмент: ``(`orders`.`partner_id` IS NULL AND `author`.`is_statistic` = 1 OR ( `orders`.`partner_id` IS NOT NULL AND `author`.`is_statistic` = 1 AND `partner`.`is_statistic` = 1))`` - из него явно можно вынести ``(`author`.`is_statistic` = 1)``.

Comment: у вас раздел Каталог состоит только из этой информации? Или все же это просто какой-то побочный контент, который просто тормозит загрузку всей страницы, чем и не доволен клиент? Если так дак помимо оптимизации, загружайте этот блок вообще отдельно аяксом.

Comment: Я замерял время загрузки всего раздела. Основное потребление времени приходится на этот запрос. Он выполняется за 0,33 сек. Для 10 товаров получится более трех секунд